# Foundation and equalizer not good user experience

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

New with foundation . I'm using foundation 5 together with equalizer - I simply have a row with 2 columns , one has some text and the other has an image .  I need both columns to be the same height - so I'm using data-equalizer.

```
      <div class="row collapse" data-equalizer >
        <div class=" large-6 columns main-headline story panel" data-equalizer-watch>
        <div class="large-3 columns panel end"  data-equalizer-watch>
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-2.jpg" class="main-headline-image ">
      </div>
```

Now , the problem is that since the image takes some time to load , there is an annoying lag : the first div is first rendered short and then after a couple of seconds it's height is re-calculated by equalizer (since the image has been loaded and now  equalizer gives it the height of the image div) and it stretches to meet the height of the image (it's ok that it stretches that's what should happen , but it's not ok that it takes it 2-3 seconds to do so . doesn't look good at all).

Is there a strategy to deal with this ? This is an issue , since I'm developing locally and it's bad enough already, I don't want to think how'd it look in production with many more images .
I'm thinking that pre-setting the height on the columns would fix it , but isn't this a "bad" way to work with foundation? Is giving the columns a pre-determined height ruining the responsiveness of the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

If your image is too fat,
you will still suffer that "resize atfter 2-3 seconds" effect, foundation or not.
Giving a fixed height to the column is a bad idea, due to the responsiveness loss.

Alternatives are:

1. optimize your image dramatically
2. show that block with foundation equalizer only after images are loaded